# Included Module method not found in class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting no method found error for my module methods. They are defined like so:

```
module MyModule
  def my_method
    "stuff"
  end
end
```

And the class is like this:

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
  def self.do_stuff
    my_method
  end
end
```

Then I'm trying to call it like so:

```
MyClass.do_stuff
```

I'm getting

```
undefined method 'my_method" for MyClass:Class
```

I have also tried

```
self.my_method
```

in the Module, but no luck. I should mention this is a vanilla ruby class within a rails application. application.rb includes the following line

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

and in the console I can verify that the module is getting loaded.
Any ideas on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you want to use extend to make the method a class method.

```
class MyClass
  extend MyModule
  def self.do_stuff
    my_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Define functions in module as `module_function` and it should work.

```
module MyModule
  module_function
  def my_method
    "stuff"
  end
end
```